# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Definitely lots of open questions that should've been closed. This is very common here - votes expire before they get enough.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure we all love it, @Community♦. I view it as an impediment, for the most part. Though not as much so as English Language & Usage SE. The fact that fewer than 10 users out of [How Many?](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/users) bothered to answer that questionnaire might perhaps give a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is the difference between assertive and non-assertive words?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8784/what-is-the-difference-between-assertive-and-non-assertive-words)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Georgian minimal pairs with p' t' k'](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8651/georgian-minimal-pairs-with-p-t-k)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Possible methods of input for languages with a lot of diacritic characters](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8732/possible-methods-of-input-for-languages-with-a-lot-of-diacritic-characters)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is it possible to identify a language without hearing the words?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8664/why-is-it-possible-to-identify-a-language-without-hearing-the-words)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Any difference between natural and programming languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8612/any-difference-between-natural-and-programming-languages)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why are these Sanskrit words in the nominative case](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8756/why-are-these-sanskrit-words-in-the-nominative-case)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [A multilingual home, a pro or a con?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8794/a-multilingual-home-a-pro-or-a-con)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Is Language infinite?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/is-language-infinite)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How can I detect Formants programatically](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/how-can-i-detect-formants-programatically)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Where on the Internet can I find sound files so that I can hear the alveo-palatal consonants?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8723/where-on-the-internet-can-i-find-sound-files-so-that-i-can-hear-the-alveo-palata)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---